# fi syntax error and unexpected end of file

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do you want to Login or Sign Up?"

read ans

if [ "$ans" = "Sign Up" ]

then
echo "You are creating a account"
echo "Create a Username"
read ipr4
clear
echo "Create a Password"
read pwd
touch $pwd &
touch $ipr4 &
read ip
else
clear
echo "Type in your Username"
read pwed
clear

if [ -f $pwed ]; then
echo "Type in your password"
read pass
clear

if [ -f $pass ]; then
echo "Choose a application (To run the proggramm of your choise just type in the name of the proggramm)"
echo " | Ecryption | Chat | Spamming Chat | Quiz | "
read act
if [ "$act" == "Encryption" ]
then
     echo "Do you want to encrypt or decrypt message (Type in encrypt to encrypt a message in base64. Type in decrypt to decrypt a message that was encrypted in base 64)"
read ans
if [ "$ans" = "encrypt" ]
then

     echo "Please enter your message"
read enc
     echo "Your encrypted message is:"
     echo  -n $enc | base64
    echo "Please enter the message that you want to decipher"
read dec
    echo "Your deciphered message is:"
    echo -n $dec | base64 -D
    echo " "
if [ "$act" == "Chat" ] then
echo "Want to be a the Host (yes/no)"
read y

if [ "$y" ==  "yes" ]
then

clear
echo "Which port"
read port
clear
echo "You are on port: $port"
nc -l $port
else
if [ "$y" == "no" ]
then
clear
echo "Which port do you want to chat on"
read p2
echo "What is the listeners IPv4"
read ipi4
clear
echo "You are chatting to $ipi4 on Port: $p2"
nc $ipi4 $p2
else
if [ "$act" == "Spamming Chat"]
then
clear
echo "Want to be a listener (yes/no)"
read y
if [ "$y" ==  "yes" ]
then
clear
echo "Which port"
read port
clear
echo "You are on port: $port"
echo "Which message do you want to spam"
read spamm
echo "You are chatting to $ipv4 on Port: $p2"
mkfifo fifo_filename
nc -l $p2 <fifo_filename &

exec 3>fifo_filename
while true
do
        echo "$spamm"
        sleep 0.001
done >&3
if [ "$act" == "Quiz" ]
then
clear
  echo "Hello this is a test"
  echo "You will be asked 3 questions and each one has two options to choose from.
There is just one correct answer for each question."

  echo "Q1: Is black a colour (yes or no)"
read q1
if [ "$q1" = "no" ]
then
   q1=1
   echo "Correct,you recieved $q1 point"
else
   q1=0
   echo "Wrong you recieved $q1 points"


  echo "Q2:Who painted the Mona Lisa (Aristotle or Da Vinci)"
read q2
if [ "$q2" = "Da Vinci" ]
then
   q2=1
   echo "Correct you recieved $q2 point"
if [ "q2" -ne "Da Vinci" ]
then
  q2=0
  echo "Wrong you recieved $q2 points"

 echo "You now have $(($q1+$q2)) points"

 echo "Q3:Who invented the seatbelt (Volvo or Porsche)"
if [ "$q3" = "Volvo" ]
then
  q3=1
 echo "Correct you recieved $q3 point"
if [ "$q3" -ne "Volvo" ]
then
 q3=0
 echo "Wrong you unfortunately recieved $q3 points"
sleep 4
clear
sleep 2
echo "Congratulations you scored  $(($q1+$q2+$q3))/3"
fi
fi
fi
else
if [ -f -ne $pass ];then
clear
sleep 2
echo "login failed"
echo "4 fi down"
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
fi
```

So this piece of code should be a basic system that allows you to use several programms that are embedded in the code. It always gives me two errors fi syntax error and when I correct the code it gives me the alert unexpected end of file and that goes on and on. Can anyone come up with a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7):

I count 17 `if`s and only 11 `fi`s. Close the `if`s with `fi`s.

Also indent the code properly.